# CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE error for large files with libcurl

Tags: android, libcurl

I have linked libcurl library (v7.38.0) statically with my C++ 
application. Using curl, we upload & download files to/from server https. I Have 
download fails with the error CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE. This issue occurs 
randomly ie., some times the file was downloaded successfully without 
issue and some times, the same file fails with the error.

This issue occurs in android platforms. Anyone can show me how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE means that the transfer was aborted before the full contents arrived. That typically means a bad server or a network problem, *not* a client-side problem.

If you cannot affect the network or server conditions, you probably need to consider ignoring this particular error.