# Curl download giving error CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE for large file download

Tags: curl, libcurl

We are using curl library 7.73.0 . Its being linked with the source code. Using Curl we download the big files from the HTTP server. This file is of size 750 MB. During the download it is seen that at times we get CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE error.  I wanted to understand the cause of this error.  Its entering this loop of transfer.c file in Curl library and aborting. I wanted to understand what does this loop exactly indicate.

```
if(!(data->set.opt_no_body) && k->chunk &&
   (conn->chunk.state != CHUNK_STOP)) {
  /*
   * In chunked mode, return an error if the connection is closed prior to
   * the empty (terminating) chunk is read.
   *
   * The condition above used to check for
   * conn->proto.http->chunk.datasize != 0 which is true after reading
   * *any* chunk, not just the empty chunk.
   *
   */
  failf(data, "transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining");
  return CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE;
}
```

If anyone could explain what the above check is supposed to represent, it would be helpful. We want to debug this issue to consider if we have a problem in TCP reassembly on the client side or is it a server/network issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CURLE\_PARTIAL\_FILE error for large files with libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026326/curle-partial-file-error-for-large-files-with-libcurl)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was indeed in the server where it was stopping the transfer midway.